# How can I standardize a data set that consists of mean and standard deviation columns using R function scale()?

Tags: r

```
state   mean    stddev
AL  6.644951923 2.527530057
AK  8.033173077 1.464966147
AZ  6.120673077 1.743671664
AR  6.474038462 1.48800798
CA  7.204086538 1.833833993
CO  5.383653846 1.394851848
CT  5.181730769 1.630995818
```

Here's a segment of the data set if that helps.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried looking at the documentation for `scale()`? Please see how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: This is the documentation for the scale function: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/scale.html

Comment: I guess I'm not really sure where to begin. From what I've researched, center and scale should be true. I'm not sure what to put for the "x" argument.

Comment: Your matrix of data